# What is the significance of the ten azharos of tshuva (in Yeshaya ch. 1)?

Tags: words, rashi, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book, aseres-yemei-teshuva

[Rashi in Yeshayah chapter 1 vs. 16](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15932#showrashi=true&v=16) tells us that the ten words in the next two psukim, רחצו, הזכו, הסירו, חדלו, למדו, דרשו, אשרו, שפטו, ריבו, are all אזהרות של לשון תשובה כנגד עשרת ימי תשובה, וכנגד עשרה מלכיות זכרונות שופרות [warnings to do teshuva, 10 phrases correspond to the 10 days of repentance (in between Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur), and to correspond to the 10 verses of מלכיות זכרונות ושופרות (the blessings that appear in the prayers of Rosh Hashanah)].

Is anyone aware of an explanation to this? Are these words in a specific order to correspond to a particular day of the עשרת ימי תשובה? Or are they all applicable in a general sense?